# How to fix PHP $_GET to work with SEO friendly URLS

Tags: php, apache

I am using WAMP for a design site and am having issues with SEO friendly URLS. I have verified that the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  is enabled. For example, my htaccess file has the following entries:

```
RewriteRule ^content-all$ content-all.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-one/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ content.php?parm1=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-two/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ content-two.php?parm1=$1&parm2=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-three/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ content-three.php?parm1=$1&parm2=$2&parm3=$3 [L]
```

All of the URL rewrites work.  However when I go to ready the parameters in each file with a $_GET command I am successful with one parameter, but unsuccessful with the two and three parameter files.
I’ve put a print_r($_GET); command and the array is empty when passing more than one value.   This should work but it is not.

I even have my httpd.conf with

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require all denied
</Directory>


RewriteRule ^content-all$ content-all.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-one/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ content.php?parm1=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-two/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ content-two.php?parm1=$1&parm2=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^content-three/([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ content-three.php?parm1=$1&parm2=$2&parm3=$3 [L]
```

I should have my $_GET array with more than one value depending on which I pass.

Comment: Some more detailed observations? Such as the first parameter slurping up all string sections? Rewrite log?

Comment: I just tested this same code under Apache2.2.21 and it works as designed, all URL rewrites and $_GET arrays are correctly populated.  It has to do with Apache version 2.4.37, and I think it has do do with the Directory section of the httpd.conf file but I don't know how to fix this.  Any ideas?